# Importing on demand within component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Below, I have 2 options to import my `ManageUser` component.  The first is how I've always imported components but my coworker showed me the 2nd way.  I assume that loads on demand but what exactly is going on there under the hood? Wouldn't it *always* be good then to just import all components like that?

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <button @click="showMe = !showMe">Show me {{ showMe}}</button>
    <ManageUser v-if="showMe"></ManageUser>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

// TWO options to import ManageUser

import ManageUser from './components/ManageUser';
const ManageUser = () => import('./components/ManageUser');


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    ManageUser
  },
  data() {
       showMe: false
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As told in the docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components
The `const ManageUser = () =>` syntax is basically lazy-loading the component. Saying that it may import it only when needed and hence, make the whole experience faster due to the fact that you do not load it on initial render.

Imagine you do have a `cart` page when you will basically checkout your sneekers on Nikee.com, if you never reach that page, what's the point to load all the logic and templating of it on the homepage ? It will be faster to only load the **needed** page on the initial render, then ask for more components as you travel around the app.

Another example could be a modal or a basically any condition that **could** be satisfied in some cases, rather not load the component if the requirement is not met.

The only time when it's not recommended is when you may need it at the initial render of a page, but you can pretty much default to the import he showed you and if you encounter a bug on some missing data/hooks, you may change it to a classic import.

Those 2 articles give more use-cases as of when to use it:

- https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-and-code-splitting-in-vue-js/
- https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/lazy-loading-individual-vue-components-and-prefetching/

TLDR: I do recommend using as much as you can.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, thanks for this question. I think You make a point, which is worthy to discuss. Also the answer of kissu is good, but I'd like to dispute one aspect a bit:

> The only time when it's not recommended is when you may need it at the initial render of a page, but you can pretty much default to the import he showed you and if you encounter a bug on some missing data/hooks, you may change it to a classic import.

I wouldn't recommend to lazy load everything, even if it is not immediately visible. Though it is true, that lazy-load will reduce the initial time to load a webpage, because the the initial data is smaller, you have to take in mind, that lazy loading in comparison to loading everything at once, will increase load time, in case that everything of a webpage, or mostly everything will be loaded at some point afterwards. This is because every request and the following response have to travel the distance from the server to the client (so both together will result in the [round trip time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-trip_delay)). If You load everything at once, there will only be one rtt.

So now, when to really use lazy loading and when not? I cannot answer to that in a profound manner, but I would recommend to use lazy loading on "big chuncks" of data, which are not needed for the initial render of the page and not likely to be needed by all users, because they would increase initial load time significantly and hinder a smooth appearance of the website. It may however be beneficial to include "Small chuncks", which on the opposite are needed on many places on the website, even if they may not be needed initially, in the initial load.

So I'm sorry, this is not an easy "yes" or "no" answer. But I hope You can develope a feeling for when lazy load is beneficial and when not. To my mind, if You have no experience, gather some. I would begin without any lazy loading  on the page (except maybe for obvious parts) and then begin to introduce lazy loading. In most modern browsers You can analyze the load time of a webpage by switching to the "networks"-tab in the developer-tools. There You can (for most browsers) also simulate "throttling" (e.g. for mobile connections, etc.). Analize the load time including the rtt-times before making a final decision, if lazy-loading is appropriate or not. Be aware, that rtt for the same country is smaller, than for hopping continents.

Be also aware, that lazy loading can not only be applied to components, but in principle to all parts of a webpage (images, html, css, javascript, ...).